# Uubuntu Software Centre - Transparent window

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Am new to Ubuntu.
I set the window to dark window theme (to reduce eye strain) and the Software Centre window becomes transparent.
I tried using a different theme but it doesn't fix the matter.

I'm sure it is my ineptitude at work

Comment: Which theme did you use? Can you post a screenshot? Since you are a new user, Ask Ubuntu won't allow you to post the screenshot directly, but it will still allow you to post a link.

Comment: I used the dark theme. I was thinking about this last night. I tried to use an image as a background; it wasn't OK so I changed back to the default background image; the transparency thing happened after that. That might be the cause?